# Getting the state of checkbox preference from an activity in android

Tags: android

i have kept background music for my android app by default.I have used preference for closing the music when the user wants.Now i want to check in an activity whether the checkbox is checked or not..How  can i access the preference checkbox from any other activity..How can i implement it?

Comment: Explain your problem little bit with your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("pref",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean x = preferences.getBoolean("mycheckbox",false);
```

"mycheckbox" is the key that you have used when creating preference check box.

```
<CheckBoxPreference 
    android:key="mycheckbox"/>
```